# Android Fragement Manager vs Navigation

Tags: android

I'm not that experienced with fragments in Android. Now I need to create an app with multiple tabs, every tab has its own back stack. I am aware that there are several third-party libraries for that and Google has some open issues with BottomNavigationView if I'm not mistaken. So what is the better way to implement this thing?

Comment: `ViewPager` with `TabLayout`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your design and needs

But I think `BottomNavigationView` is better. you can use [Navigation Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) for multiple tabs